# Subscription's onReady called when cursor is not ready

Tags: coffeescript, meteor

I am publishing some non-cursor text data from a Meteor server to a Meteor client who is subscribed to that data. The client's subscription is in a Deps.autorun function and the subscription is successfully called when a dependent variable changes.

However, I want to parse the text data as soon as it comes in, so I figured I would do this in the subscribe's onReady function. This works fine for the first time the data is sent, but on subsequent publishing of different data, the onReady function still uses the previous data.

I am wondering how I can parse the data after it has come through completely?

See below for code & output examples:
(For completeness: I am using Meteor 0.8.1.3 on Windows 8.1, client is Chrome 35)

Client:

```
cursor = new Meteor.Collection "data"

reactiveInput = 0
dep = new Deps.Dependency

window.setReactiveInput = (newVal) ->
  dep.changed()
  reactiveInput = newVal

getReactiveInput = ->
  dep.depend()
  reactiveInput

Deps.autorun ->
  Meteor.subscribe "loadData", getReactiveInput(), (r) ->
    console.log "data ready"
    for o, i in cursor.find().fetch()
      console.log i, o.value
    # Returns correct data on first call
    # Returns original data on second call
    # Returns second data on third call, etc...
```

Server:

```
Meteor.publish "loadData", (input) ->
  time = Date.now()
  for x in [0..parseInt(input)]
    @added "data", x, {value: time}
  @ready()
```

Sample output:

```
data ready
0 1402208546540 

> setReactiveInput(1)
1
data ready
0 1402208546540
1 1402208551687 

> setReactiveInput(2)
2
data ready
0 1402208551687
1 1402208551687
2 1402208553949
```

Comment: Same issue here. Very annoying. Tested with Meteor 0.8.3 and WINDOWS-PREVIEW@0.0.8.

Comment: Same issue occurs when trying to use the cursor in if (subscriptionHandle.ready()) { ... } rather than in onReady() callback.

Comment: I have submitted an issue to the Meteor team: https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3194

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't need actual cursor data, I figured I could simply call Meteor methods to get the required data. However, I still think that it is odd that the cursor's data is not updated correctly in the original case.

Solution:

Client:

```
Deps.autorun ->
  Meteor.call "loadData", getReactiveInput(), (e, result) ->
    console.log "data ready"
    for o, i in result
      console.log i, o.value
```

Server:

```
Meteor.methods
  loadData: (input) ->
    result = []
    time = Date.now()
    for x in [0..parseInt(input)]
      result.push {value: time}
    return result
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what could explain your issue:

In `onReady`, the expected behavior is to see client data updated with **added records**, not **removed ones**. The full explanation is [here](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/3194#issuecomment-69113856).

Here is a workaround: wait a bit before accessing the data, so that subscription cancelling has been resolved.

```
Tracker.autorun(function()  {   
    Meteor.subscribe('myCollection', Session.equals('whatever', true), function onReady() {
        Meteor.setTimeout(function() {
            console.log(MyCollection.find({}).fetch());     
        }, 0);
    });
});
```